# Run multiple sweetalerts after eachother

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert

I tried to run multiple sweetalerts after eachother but the code I have right now, just executes the last one. Does anybody know why and how to fix this?

```
const { value: inhalt } = Swal.fire({
  title: 'Neue Ladegüter',
  text: 'Geben Sie einen Inhalt an:',
  input: 'text',
  showCancelButton: true,
  inputValidator: (value) => {
    if (!value) {
      return 'Field cannot be empty'
    }
  }
});

const { value: beschreibung } = Swal.fire({
  title: 'Neue Ladegüter',
  text: 'Geben Sie eine Beschreibung an:',
  input: 'text',
  showCancelButton: true,
  inputValidator: (value) => {
    if (!value) {
      return 'Field cannot be empty'
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you call an alert , it will close the last one and then open new one. it use one container to show the alert. you should call other alert on response of last alert.

**Edit : example added**

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Neue Ladegüter',
  text: 'Geben Sie einen Inhalt an:',
  input: 'text',
  showCancelButton: true,
  inputValidator: (value) => {
    if (!value) {
      return 'Field cannot be empty'
    }
  }
}).then((res)=>{
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Neue Ladegüter',
      text: 'Geben Sie eine Beschreibung an:',
      input: 'text',
      showCancelButton: true,
      inputValidator: (value) => {
        if (!value) {
          return 'Field cannot be empty'
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide a short example of what you mean?

Comment: example added in my answer